# Honda Civic Power Plug

Tags: honda, battery, civic

I own a 2006 Honda Civic Coupe and I’ve looked all over the car for the plug to plug it into the power outlet. Normally in most vehicles I’ve seen they hang out of the hood of the car, but I can’t seem to find mine. Does anyone know where this would be located?

Normally I have a car started which I set to start every couple hours during cold weather, but recently after a dead battery my car starter gets my car to click but not actually start. We hit less than -30 today and my car won’t start, so I need to plug it in.

Comment: Do you have a block heater or battery charger fitted? If not then that may explain no plug...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is called a "block heater." It is an option, not all cars have them. I've had to have one installed on one of my vehicles as it didn't have one, despite -30C being a normal occurrence in my area as well.

Comment: Thanks! I was able to get one put in and it fixed the issue!:D